# create thumbnails of Vimeo videos programmatically

Tags: files

I am wondering if there is a way to create thumbnails of Vimeo videos programmatically. e.g. is there a function like image_style_url() to create an image derivative given a style and image path?
thanks.

Comment: Are you looking to 'retrieve' rather than 'create' video thumbnails?  I just reread the title and realized my answer may not be appropriate.

Comment: Taking preview image of vimeo videos is a built in feature as a media style in the media_vimeo module. i mean is there any specific function to retrieve and then create the styled image preview of vimeo videos?

Answer (score 3):

You you can use the [Vimeo Simple API](http://vimeo.com/api/docs/simple-api) to get the video thumbnails.

There is a fantastic write up [here on stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361149/get-img-thumbnails-from-vimeo) so I won't reinvent the wheel, but for a quick re-cap you can use the following code (thank you @Fluffy from link above.)

```
<?php

//Video ID - Easy to find in URL (example ID below)
$video_id = (int) 6271487;

//Format you would like returned. (Can be php, xml or json)
$format = (string) 'php';

//Build request URL
$request_URL = "http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/$video_id.$format";

//Get data and unserialize
$response = unserialize(file_get_contents($request_URL"));

//Echo's url to image.
echo $response[0]['thumbnail_medium'];  

?>
```

Optionally, check out the [Vimeo Advanced API](http://vimeo.com/api/docs/advanced-api) method: [vimeo.videos.getThumbnailUrls](http://vimeo.com/api/docs/methods/vimeo.videos.getThumbnailUrls)